# Get value from sharepoint list using c# returning extra characters for termstore values

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Hi im using spquery to look up items in a list in sharepoint 2010 and most fields are working correctly, but some fields are returning extra values after the string. eg

> Transfield|a1150311-39dd-4112-897e-6b2c96ea9fa5

It seems to be only the termset values, how can I convert them to text properly?

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
if (items != null)
{
     SPListItem item = items[0];
     ServiceProvider.Text = item["ServiceProvider"].ToString();
     Structures.Text = item["Structures"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely reason is `ToString` for the type of "filed value" you are getting is not returning what you want.

You should find what type of this field is and get correct property of the resulting value. To find type - look at type of `item["Structures"]`.

I.e. for Url field ( [SPFieldUrlValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurlvalue_members.aspx) ) you can use `Url` property instead of `ToString`:

```
 var url = ((SPFieldUrlValue)item["SomeUrlFieldName"]).Url
```

Comment: The field value is a taxonomy type, what would I use for that?

Comment: I don't know... Basic search reveals [TaxonomyFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvalue%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class which is probably what you want...